# Angular 2 AOT Compilation for JS sources

Tags: angular

How can one compile ngfactories for Javascript sources? The [ngc compiler](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) is documented on the AOT page, but the tool itself is coupled to tsc.

The sources being compiled could follow angular's js api docs, or closely resemble the js emitted when using ngc.